# Ground state of particle in a ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In the ground state of a [particle in a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_ring), the boundary conditions allow the particle to have energy equal to zero. This sounds that the momentum is completely defined and, according to the uncertainty principle, the position in the ring is undefined. Is it correct to say that, in this state, the particle is at rest but we don't know where?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150435/discussion-on-question-by-physical-chemist-ground-state-of-particle-in-a-ring); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

The eigenfunctions should look something like:

$$ \psi_n(\theta) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{in\theta} $$

for integer $n$. Putting in the time dependence:

$$ \psi_n(\theta, t) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i(n\theta-E_nt)} $$

which corresponds to a wave propagating around the ring. You didn't post the hamiltonian, but it should be easy to find $E_0=0$, which does correspond to an at rest particle, and being at rest, it's probability is evenly distributed around the ring.

Actually, it looks likes:

$$|\psi_n|^2 = \frac 1 {2\pi} $$

for all $n$, so all eigenstates are equal distributed.

Two things to look at are:

1)

$$ E_n = E_{-n} $$

are degenerate, so you can mix them with a phase difference and make standing waves with $2n$ nodes various offsets.

2. Compute the probability current and see if it flows around the ring.

Comment: Good. Then, the particle is at rest, right? But, if the probability density is uniform, the position of particle in the ring is completely undetermined, since all positions have the same probability. Is it right?

Comment: yes. And state with $n=0$ and/or equal weight on $n$ and $-n$ are at rest, though the later is not uniform. I suggest you calculate it from the eigenfunction, then you will know the answer for sure.

Comment: @PhysicalChemist The particle in the ground state has zero kinetic energy, because when we apply the KE operator to a flat function gives zero. I think going the next step and saying it is at rest is bringing in classical physics baggage. 

As for position being completely undetermined, your language is very loose. Other wave functions that aren't like dirac deltas have continuous distributions, and we say that the position is indeterminate until a measurement is made. We can say a general position measurement is $\textit{completely}$ undetermined until a measurement is made.